# How make input not rebind the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a input on page in some div:

```
<input style='border:1px solid black;' type='text' id='inputFindBy_Name' />
```

and o jquery javascript function monitored it:

```
 $("div[id=mainGridPage] input").bind("keyup", function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                var searchField = "Name";
            var searchValue = $(this)[0].value;
            var pageIndex = "1";
            var sortField = "Name";
            Application.Services.ProductTypeService.LoadMainGridProductType(pageIndex, sort, sortField, searchField, searchValue, ResultLoadMainGridProductType, ErrorLoadMainGridProductType);
            }
        });
```

when user typed something and pressed ENTER (`event.keyCode == 13`) I need do some thing but without reloading the page. How do that?

Comment: What do you need to do?  Few of the things you can do there will cause a reload.  You need to be more specific.

Comment: I start some service and get request on this javascript file.

Comment: So I'm guessing that is in a form that has an `action`.  Is there a reason you can't simply not give it an `action` property?

Comment: does this input associate with any form?

Comment: in this div block may be more than one input, so I try to write a selector that listen more than one input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return `false` from within the function:

```
var code = event.keyCode || event.which;
if (code == 13) {
    // do what you have to do.....
    return false;
}
```

**Edit**: the `keyup` event is triggered "too late" after the form submission event was already dispatched - you can't cancel or stop it in that stage. So, handle the `keypress` event instead. Change the line to:

```
$("div[id=mainGridPage] input").bind("keypress", function (event) {
```

And the `return false;` will indeed stop the form from submitting.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/jA2bP/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
$("div[id=mainGridPage] input").bind("keyup", function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            // needed do something here without reloading the page
            return false;
        }

    });
```

just like a link.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a `event.stopPropagation()` and maybe the `return false;`. Please use `event.which` because `event.keyCode` is not compatible with all browsers, also you are using `div[id=mainGridPage] input` which searches for an ID, a better way to put this down is: `div#mainGridPage input`, and probably faster.

```
    $("div#mainGridPage input").bind("keyup", function (event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            // needed do something here without reloading the page
            return false.
        }
    });
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: Why not, I'm preventing the default action, which is submitting the page on enter, and I gave some tips?

Comment: when I pressed ENTER the code note working at all. I put alert into if (event.keyCode == 13) - not appears. page reloading and not happens.

Comment: You added the "You need to do a event.preventDefault()" only after my comment - or maybe I missed it as it was in the five minutes grace period I can't know for sure.

Comment: I have changed the .preventDefault() to .stopPropagation(), but the first thing I did is .preventDefault(). But lets stop the discussion and lead to the correct answer. Updated my answer and added `return false;` to the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

try this. this will work i think:

```
$("div[id=mainGridPage] input").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        // do your code
        console.log('hello');
        return false;
    }
});
```